# Date Range-Partition in Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to range-partition a table on type integer or date. In case one, when I partition on integer, it works fine with the following query like so.

```
CREATE TABLE `project-id.dataset.parted_employee_int`
PARTITION BY RANGE_BUCKET(employee_id, GENERATE_ARRAY(1, 100000, 5000)) AS 
select employee_id, full_name, birth_date from `project-id.dataset.employee`;
```

I am trying to extend this query for date range-partition as well. Like so.

```
CREATE TABLE `project-id.dataset.parted_employee_date`
PARTITION BY RANGE_BUCKET(birth_date, GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(CAST('1912-07-09' AS DATE), CAST('1979-06-23' AS DATE), INTERVAL 2 MONTH)) AS
select employee_id, full_name, birth_date from `project-id.dataset.employee`;
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
PARTITION BY expression must be DATE(<timestamp_column>), DATE(<datetime_column>), DATETIME_TRUNC(<datetime_column>, DAY/HOUR/MONTH/YEAR), a DATE column, TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(<timestamp_column>, DAY/HOUR/MONTH/YEAR), DATE_TRUNC(<date_column>, MONTH/YEAR), or RANGE_BUCKET(<int64_column>, GENERATE_ARRAY(<int64_value>, <int64_value>[, <int64_value>]))
```

how to rang-partition on date ?  Is there a way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the supported methods of partitioning are listed [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#partition_expression).

The closest out-of-the-box feature that you may use is partition by MONTH.

Comment: Link is an internal Google site

Comment: @YunZhang is there a way to provide lowerBound and upperBound for Date-range partition similar to Integer-Range partition ?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do that

Answer (score 0):

To be more precise, here's how to Partition on date using `PARTITION BY DATE(<date_column>, MONTH/YEAR)`

```
CREATE TABLE `project-id.dataset.parted_employee_date`
PARTITION BY DATE_TRUNC(birth_date, MONTH) AS
select employee_id, full_name, birth_date from `project-id.dataset.employee`;
```

If I wanted to partition on DAY or HOUR, I have to use `PARTITION BY DATETIME_TRUNC(<datetime_column>, DAY/HOUR/MONTH/YEAR)`

Hence first, I have to cast `birth_date` to `DATETIME` in the select clause.

```
CREATE TABLE `project-id.dataset.parted_employee_date_time`
PARTITION BY DATETIME_TRUNC(birth_date_dt, MONTH) AS
select employee_id, full_name, CAST (birth_date AS DATETIME) as birth_date_dt
from `project-id.dataset.employee`;
```